# How to set underline on hover on navigation links on responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have coded for underline on hover on the navigation menu, which works well. But when I create a responsive navigation menu, the underline on hover covers the entire width of the block rather than the navigation link, as it does when the browser is greater than 600px.

[Here's the site](http://staging1.oakpark.co/), or you can refer to the below snippet.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lyon";
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf");
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("woff"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("opentype"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("svg");
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .05rem solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-style: none;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float;
    none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.responsive {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
  <a href="#about" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="#lindsay">Lindsay</a>
  <a href="#contact">Branding</a>
  <a href="#contact">Photography</a>
  <a href="#contact">Instagram</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">i</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking your CSS and the problem is that `a` tag has the property of `display:block` which expand the tag, so, the styles applies to the tag itself, no in the text, so, if you want to preserve the space when the display is smaller, you should wrap each `a` tag in a list item or in a `div`, and pass it the property of `display:block`

**this is the example using that I said**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lyon";
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf");
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("woff"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("opentype"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("svg");
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .05rem solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 14px 16px;
 margin: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li{
 list-style:none;
}

.navbar a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-style: none;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a{
    display: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
  }
  .navbar .icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  .navbar.responsive li a {
    float;
    none;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
  }
 .navbar.responsive li {
    float;
    none;
    text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 00px;
  }
  .navbar.responsive {
    align-content: center;
  flex-flow:column;
  }
  .navbar.responsive li a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .navbar.responsive li a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">i</a>
 <li><a href="#about" class="active">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#lindsay">Lindsay</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Branding</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Photography</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Axel and Zero. Thanks for getting back to me with a solution. Both of these worked and I understand your solution was a temporary one, Zero. They both worked but the underline on hover was off when displayed on an iPhone when using the 'nthchild' method even if it displayed correctly on a computer. The 'list' method works across both platforms. I appreciate your input!

Comment: If the solutions works, please accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting like this

**Temporary Solution**

I have just added nth-child and given scaling for each link.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lyon";
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf");
  src: url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("woff"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("opentype"), url("http://staging1.oakpark.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Lyon-Text-Regular.otf") format("svg");
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: .05rem solid;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navbar a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-style: none;
  font-family: 'Lyon';
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 6px;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 8px;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float;
    none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.responsive {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width:100%;
    
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:nth-child(1):before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.18);
    transform: scaleX(.18);
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:nth-child(2):before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.22);
    transform: scaleX(.22);
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:nth-child(3):before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.25);
    transform: scaleX(.25);
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:nth-child(4):before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.33);
    transform: scaleX(.33);
  }
  .navbar.responsive a:hover:nth-child(5):before {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(.26);
    transform: scaleX(.26);
  }
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
  <a href="#about" class="active">About</a>
  <a href="#lindsay">Lindsay</a>
  <a href="#contact">Branding</a>
  <a href="#contact">Photography</a>
  <a href="#contact">Instagram</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">i</a>
</div>
```

---

Comment: Hi Axel and Zero. Thanks for getting back to me with a solution. Both of these worked and I understand your solution was a temporary one, Zero. They both worked but the underline on hover was off when displayed on an iPhone when using the 'nthchild' method even if it displayed correctly on a computer. The 'list' method works across both platforms. I appreciate your input!